# riscv64 linux kernel compilation issue

Tags: qemu, riscv

I am trying to compile the linux kernel for riscv64 using the following link -

https://risc-v-getting-started-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/linux-qemu.html

While building linux with the command make ARCH=riscv CROSS_COMPILE=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu- defconfig
the following error shows up -
scripts/kconfig.include:35 compiler riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc not found in PATH
scripts/kconfig/Makefile:82:recipe for target 'defconfig' failed

I have included path of tool chain. Still not working. Attached the screenshot of folder structure and error.[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the package manager to install qemu? Full installations come with riscv-system-riscv32 and 64 variants.

Answer (score 1):

It is saying `compiler riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu not found` which means either riscv gnu toolchain is not installed on your machine or it is not found by the shell instance in which you are trying to compile linux kernel.

To check if RISC-V GNU toolchain is installed, create a simple C file and try to compile it with RISC-V gnu toolchain with following command:

```
riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc <filename.c> -o <binaryname>
```

**1. If RISC-V GNU Toolchain is not installed:**
Follow the instruction [here](https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain) to install riscv gnu toolchain. And keep in mind to compile it with `make linux` instead of `make`.

**2. If RISC-V GNU Toolchain is installed or you are done installing**
Add it to the `$PATH` variable inside `.bashrc` file located on home directory.

Then try compiling your kernel again.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to provide the full prefix for your toolchain in the `make` command, for example:

```
wget https://toolchains.bootlin.com/downloads/releases/toolchains/riscv64/tarballs/riscv64--glibc--bleeding-edge-2020.02-2.tar.bz2
mkdir -p /opt/bootlin
tar jxf riscv64--glibc--bleeding-edge-2020.02-2.tar.bz2 -C /opt/bootlin

make ARCH=riscv CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/bootlin/riscv64--glibc--bleeding-edge-2020.02-2/bin/riscv64-buildroot-linux-gnu- mrproper defconfig Image
```

Compilation should complete without errors - using linux 5.7.11 here:

```
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/confdata.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/expr.o
  LEX     scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c
  YACC    scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.[ch]
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.o
  .../...
  LD      vmlinux.o
  MODPOST vmlinux.o
  MODINFO modules.builtin.modinfo
  GEN     modules.builtin
  LD      .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1
  KSYM    .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.o
  LD      .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2
  KSYM    .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.o
  LD      vmlinux
  SYSMAP  System.map
  OBJCOPY arch/riscv/boot/Image
  Kernel: arch/riscv/boot/Image is ready
```

Comment: @Yulia: did this answer your question ?